# How to fill area between two sets of data connected by line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two sets of data that are shown like lines in graph. How to fill with color area between them?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
curve1, = plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
curve2, = plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
```

I tried:

```
x = np.arange(0,12,0.01)
plt.fill_between(x, curve1, curve2, color='yellow')
```

Thank you

Comment: is your `xdata` the same as `x`? I assume that yes in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `ydata` as arguments for your [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html), not the curves.

**Either use `ydata` directly, or get them from your `curve1/2` objects like `ydata=curve1.get_ydata()`**.

Here is an example adapted from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/whats_new_98_4_fill_between.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-whats-new-98-4-fill-between-py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
y1 = -5*x*x + x + 10
y2 = 5*x*x + x

c1, = plt.plot(x, y1, color='black')
c2, = plt.plot(x, y2, color='black')

# If you want/have to get the data form the plots
# x = c1.get_xdata()
# y1 = c1.get_ydata()
# y2 = c2.get_ydata()

plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 >y1, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 <=y1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Fill Between')

plt.show()
```

In the end you get:

[image]

Comment: Can I write `y1 = curve1` and `y2 = curve2`? I have plotted the curves, so can I skip ax.plot? Is there a problem I plotted it by plt.plot?

Comment: Well, `curve1` is a `Line2D` object, so what you can do is using `curve1.get_ydata()` which is essentially your `ydata` again.

Comment: no, there is not problem when using `plt` instead of `ax` to plot. If you use `plt` it simply plots on the current axes.

Comment: If you don't want the lines then simply do the `fill_between` using your `xdata` and `ydata`. The line is not needed for this, so you do not need to do `plot` at all if you don't need the lines.

Comment: @LukášAltman I have adapted my answer to only use `plt` without defining an `axes` object explicitly, just as you did.